What is the proper way to handle mypy [attr-defined] errors, due to transitions dynamically adding is_* attributes?
MRE
from transitions import Machine


class TradingSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=['RUNNING'], initial='RUNNING')

    def check_running(self) -> None:
        if self.is_RUNNING():              
            print("System is running")

Example usage
system = TradingSystem()
system.check_running()

Issue
mypy transitions_mypy.py

gives the error:
transitions_mypy.py:9: error: "TradingSystem" has no attribute "is_RUNNING"  [attr-defined]

This can be avoided by bypassing mypy, for example adding # type: ignore[attr-defined] at the end of line 9.
But what is the proper way? Is it better to avoid bypassing mypy? Perhaps by manually defining the attribute?

Does pytransitions offer a mypy plugin?

According to https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/574 "transitions 0.9.0 has been published to PyPI and include typing stub files."
But I'm not familiar with the term "mypy plugin".

Mypy supports a plugin system that allows packages to customize how mypy checks code that uses them: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending_mypy.html#extending-mypy-using-plugins. For example, numpy's mypy plugin. pytransition would need to provide a plugin in order for mypy to know about the dynamic attributes that it defines

The answer @Mark proposed won't work since transitions does not override already existing model attributes because that would be unexpected (mis)behaviour (as @Mark pointed out). If you enable logging, transitions will also tell you that:
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

The output should contain:
WARNING:transitions.core:Model already contains an attribute 'is_RUNNING'. Skip binding.

In the past, I suggested to inherit from Machine and override Machine._checked_assignment to workaround that safeguard. However, @james-hirschorn's approach using attrs which was posted in the transitions issue tracker is a better solution in my oppinion:
from typing import Callable
from attrs import define, field
from transitions import Machine


@define(slots=False)
class TradingSystem:
    is_RUNNING: Callable[[], bool] = field(init=False)
    stop: Callable[[], None] = field(init=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=['RUNNING', 'STOPPED'], initial='RUNNING')
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger='stop', source='RUNNING', dest='STOPPED')

    def check_running(self) -> None:
        if self.is_RUNNING():  
            print("System is running")

    def stop_system(self) -> None:
        self.stop()
        print("System stopped")

# Example usage
system = TradingSystem()
system.check_running()
system.stop_system()

This produces some overhead since you have to define triggers and convenience methods twice. Furthermore, type information are also incomplete because transitions will also add is_STOPPED and auto transitions like to_STOPPED/RUNNING or 'peek' transition methods such as may_stop to TradingSystem during runtime.
Improving transitions typing support is currently an open issue.

So first off, the reason this is an issue is that this "transitions" library is really misbehaving - modifying self externally in this way is not exactly good practice, e.g. what if something was already using is_RUNNING when it modified self?
That said, there is a way to solve your issue without type ignores, you just have to simulate the methods that transitions generates via a separate interface. For now I've added is_RUNNING here but you could add other methods as well:
from transitions import Machine

class TransitionsInterface:
    def is_RUNNING(self) -> bool:
        ...
    

class TradingSystem(TransitionsInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=['RUNNING'], initial='RUNNING')

    def check_running(self) -> None:
        if self.is_RUNNING():              
            print("System is running")

system = TradingSystem()
system.check_running()

Hope this helps!

The proper solution to my understanding is by @brian61354270 that transitions needs a mypy plugin. But an interface seems to be the best workaround for now.

I never tested this workaround, since I ended up using attrs, which I thought was just a variation on this. But as @aleneum points out the above code does not even work with my modification.
